# How can I protect the fonts that I made on myself?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I have made a font and I'm going to use it on my website.
But I want to make users can't download my font and use it.
What should I do to implement this challenge?

I have tried to find any solutions by using Typekit but I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good solution except displaying the font characters as images.

If you serve something to a web-browser, the user of the web-browser can download it, and re-upload it. Simple as that.

Your main tool as an author against this is copyright and the legal system.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Slava Knyazev.
However, you can at least **make copying your font an annoying task.**

**Some ideas:**

- Split your font into **subsets**. E.g. one font file containing only glyphs A-Z, another for lowercase letters, 0-9 etc.
  This way pirates would need to join and recompile seperate font files to get a  usable font.
- Embed your font subsets as **base64 data URLs** – admittedly, you can still download the font but its less convenient.
  You can use a tool like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) to generate subsets and data-URLs.
- Use a **fake font-family name**: e.g. the name of a google web font. Ideally a **name of a quite similar font**. Pirates might try to search for the font directly – adds just a little confusion.

##### Example: font split into subsets

```js
let string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
// string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
//string = '0123456789';
//console.log(string);

let range = 'unicode-range:'+string.split("").map(codepoint => 'U+'+codepoint.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, 0)).join(', ')+';';
//console.log(range)
```

```css
/* a-z */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=S6uyw4BMUTPHvxwiQW7Nf0ONi7pdh54zuqOrY__cSidcLad6Vkph&skey=2d58b92a99e1c086&v=v23) format('woff2');
unicode-range:U+0061, U+0062, U+0063, U+0064, U+0065, U+0066, U+0067, U+0068, U+0069, U+006a, U+006b, U+006c, U+006d, U+006e, U+006f, U+0070, U+0071, U+0072, U+0073, U+0074, U+0075, U+0076, U+0077, U+0078, U+0079, U+007a;
}

/* A-Z */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=S6uyw4BMUTPHvxwiQU7tX2Otq5p9p74TmoOLQ9_8agd8DYdadmpB&skey=2d58b92a99e1c086&v=v23) format('woff2');
  unicode-range:U+0041, U+0042, U+0043, U+0044, U+0045, U+0046, U+0047, U+0048, U+0049, U+004a, U+004b, U+004c, U+004d, U+004e, U+004f, U+0050, U+0051, U+0052, U+0053, U+0054, U+0055, U+0056, U+0057, U+0058, U+0059, U+005a;

}

/* 0-9 */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
    src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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') format('woff2');

  unicode-range:U+0030, U+0031, U+0032, U+0033, U+0034, U+0035, U+0036, U+0037, U+0038, U+0039;
}


*{
  font-family:'Open Sans';
  font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<h1>ABCDabcdefg0123</h1>
```

#### Convert your text to svg with opentype.js

If you need to display only samples of your font, you can parse and render text as svg `<path>` elements using [opentype.js.](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js)

```js
let svgcontainer = document.querySelector('#svgcontainer');
let inputText = document.querySelector('#inputText');
// opentype.js accepts only ttf and otf
let fontFile = 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v15/va9E4kDNxMZdWfMOD5Vvl4jO.ttf';
inputText.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let testString = e.currentTarget.value;
  let params = {
    string: testString,
    font: fontFile,
    fontSize: 100,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    decimals: 3
  }
  text2Path(params)
})

//default
let params = {
  string: inputText.value,
  font: fontFile,
  fontSize: 100,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  decimals: 3
}
text2Path(params)

function text2Path(params) {
  opentype.load(params.font, function(err, font) {
    if (!err) {
      let options = params.options;
      let path = font.getPath(params.string, params.x, params.fontSize, params.fontSize, options);
      let textPath = path.toSVG(params.decimals);
      let newSvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
      newSvg.classList.add('svgText');
      newSvg.id ='svgTextEl';
      newSvg.setAttribute('xmlns', "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
      newSvg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', textPath);
      svgcontainer.innerHTML = newSvg.outerHTML;


      // adjust bbox
      let bb = svgTextEl.getBBox();
      svgTextEl.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + (bb.width + bb.x) + ' ' + (params.fontSize * 1.5));
      
      //svgcontainer.innerHTML = newSvg.outerHTML;


      //add downloadbtn
      let btnDownload = document.createElement("a");
      btnDownload.setAttribute('download', 'font-' + params.string + '.svg');
      btnDownload.textContent = 'Download';
      let dataURl = getDataUrl(newSvg.outerHTML, 'image/svg+xml');
      btnDownload.href = dataURl;
      svgcontainer.appendChild(btnDownload)

    } else {
      console.log('Font could not be loaded: ' + err);
    }
  });
}

function getDataUrl(str, mime) {
  let dataUrl = 'data:' + mime + ';base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)))
  return dataUrl;
}
```

```css
.svgText {
  height: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@latest/dist/opentype.min.js"></script>

<div class="layout">
  <div class="frm-wrp">
    <input id="inputText" type="text" value="Test">
  </div>
  <div class="svgcontainer" id="svgcontainer"></div>
</div>
```

None of these measures is a proper protection. But at least copying your font won't be fun;)